# Define is not defined jquery.mobile.custom.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

I'm using for the 1st time jquery mobile and I have this strange error:

Uncaught ReferenceError: define is not defined jquery.mobile.custom.js:1331

Can someone figure out what is the problem?

Tnks ^^

Comment: Just a comment - I think the `easing` plugin is unnecessary because you include jQuery UI (not going to fix any problem)

Comment: Did you make any changes to `jquery.mobile.custom.js`.  The problem is related to `jquery.mobile`, and its ability to be used as an `AMD` module.  However, there is no reason it should be getting called, unless something in the file got changed and as an unforseen consequence, that part of the code got messed up OR you are using `requirejs` or something similar, and using it incorrectly.

Comment: @Ian You're right, thank you ^^

Comment: @user1167442 I simply use the jquery mobile download builder and include the file in the page. I included the minified one but, when I saw there was a problem I changed file to see where exactly was the problem.

Comment: @Shyghar did you ever resolve this? I'm running into the same issue when building with the jQuery Mobile Download Builder.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to relate to this issue from the jQuery Mobile Builder GitHub repo:
https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile-builder/issues/19

It seems to be closed now, so try re-building your jQuery Mobile with the builder again here:
http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/

Comment: Now the code give another error: 
- Cannot read property 'options' of undefined

Comment: Try doing it with the complete jquery.mobile.js file.  If you still get an error, it is likely related to a piece of your code that is causing a problem to show up where you wouldn't expect.

Comment: Another thing to look at:  open the developer console, looking at the error - press the arrow to expand the list that displays the chain of places where the error occurred.  You may see a reference to one of your other files.  If there are any other files listed that are not jquery or jquery mobile, it will point to where the coding problem is coming from.